# How do I get my password without installing Microsoft Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge, password-management

I have been using Microsoft Edge as my password manager. I am trying to get one of my passwords, but do not have Edge installed on this device. I do not want to install Edge on this device. I am on a mobile phone.

Can I access my password without installing Edge? If so, how?

I am looking for something like how Google does it with passwords.google.com.

Comment: In Edge, did you set up synchronization to your Microsoft account? Without it, passwords would not be available even with Edge installed.

Comment: @DanielB yes, it is synchronized to my Microsoft account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have used a Microsoft account then your passwords were saved in the
Microsoft cloud and can be retrieved from everywhere, by installing
the Edge app on your phone (available for Android and iPhone).

I don't think that another solution exists.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid of. Time to switch back to chrome I guess.

Comment: Or.. switch to another password manager so you aren't married to either.

Comment: You would have to install Chrome on your phone. What’s the difference between Edge and Chrome. Why allow Google and not Microsoft on it?

Comment: @Ramhound you do not need chrome to check passwords. You can use passwords.google.com.

Comment: See Bitwarden for a free multi-platform password manager, but there are others.

Comment: @Evorlor - You can do the same with a Microsoft account.

Comment: @Ramhound how? If you can tell me how, that would be an accepted and upvoted answer.

Comment: The how is in my answer. I think @Ramhound means that Bitwarden does not do more than using a Microsoft account, but I would beg to differ here.

Comment: @harrymc Passwords can be managed within a Microsoft account just like they can be managed in a Google account

Comment: @Ramhound are you saying Microsoft has an equivalent to passwords.google.com? If so, I cannot find the URL.

Comment: Also, Bitwarden can support more software than just Edge.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the tip. I'm checking out Bitwarden.

Comment: Does Bitwarden have a website to view your passwords like passwords.google.com?

Comment: Yes, you should start with the website.